# Merge an array value with another array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I Have 2 arrays:

```php
$fields = array('field1'=>'INT', 'field2'=>'STR', 'field3'=>'INT');
$values = array('pour field1', 'pour field2', 'pour field3');
```

I am looking to merge both of them to get the below result using foreach:

```php
foreach($fields as $setK=>$setV){
            
    echo 'k '.$setK.' v '.$setV.'<br />';
            
    echo "Items are $setK 'THE VALUES OF VALUES ARRAY HERE' $setV";
            
}
```

So the result will be displayed like:

```
Items are field1 pour field1 INT
Items are field2 pour field2 STR
Items are field3 pour field3 INT
```

Comment: assign the same keys to `$values`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (array_keys($fields) as $i => $key) {
    echo 'Items are ', $key, ' ', $values[$i], ' ', $fields[$key];
}
```

You need to keep a running integer count of the key offset to be able to get the same index from `$values`; we're doing this here by looping over the keys and using their index as `$i`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution with `array_map`:

```
array_map(function($key, $f, $v){
    echo "Items are ". $key. " ". $v." " . $f ."<br>";
}, array_keys($fields), $fields, $values);
```

Comment: @OumAlaa, you're welcome. Yes, `array_map` and `array_walk` are pretty convenient functions for iterating through array(s)